# Supplement for reading Group cohomology from Serre Local Fields

Tags: reference-request, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

I am doing  a reading course on Group cohomology...

I am supposed to start reading Group cohomology part in Serre's Local fields Book [http://www.amazon.com/Local-Fields-Graduate-Texts-Mathematics/dp/0387904247](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387904247)

I have had a look at Beginning Pages of  Group Cohomology part (Part III) and realized that i need to know what a functor is and what a resolution is and some other...

I know some elementary results in Projective,injective Modules...

I have not studied category theory before but i am doing category theory course (in which there is a possibility to cover resolutions) Simultaneously with this Reading course...

I am using Hilton and Stammbach's book - A Course in Homological Algebra [http://www.amazon.com/Course-Homological-Algebra-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/0387948236](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387948236) for the course that i have mentioned above which covers some category theory

The instructor for this reading course is not expecting that i should know explanation for each and every line in That book but at least some idea of what is happening....

I would be thankful if someone can suggest me some suppliments for this...

Answer (score 1):

Here are some books I've found helpful:

[Cohomology of Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387906886) - Kenneth Brown.  Very thorough, almost to a fault.  It can take a while to actually get through because of how many details are included.  If you really want to see the inner-workings of everything, work through this book and its exercises, although you may not develop any intuition in doing so.

[The Cohomology of Groups](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198535805) - Leonard Evens.  In contrast to Brown, Evens leaves a lot of details to the reader to fill in, but gets to the point a bit more quickly that way.

[An Introduction to Homological Algebra](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521559871) - Charles Weibel.  A standard text for homological algebra.  Would be a good reference text for what you're currently studying.